# Leaflet double tap does not zoom in

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Leaflet does not recognize double tap (but double click to zoom is OK - just open dev tools and choose mobile device to see the bug) on touch devices in my app: https://express-tourism.herokuapp.com/
I thought that it may be because I have map DIV inside another global wrapper DIV but that is not the case. Even when I typed 'map' in the console it shows that [doubleClickZoom is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trq7b.jpg)
Do I have to manually add that double tap feature or am I missing something?

UPDATE: @Baptiste is right - I had to add custom double tap function:

```
var tapped=false
  $("#map").on("touchstart",function(e){
    if(!tapped){ //if tap is not set, set up single tap
      tapped=setTimeout(function(){
          tapped=null
          //insert things you want to do when single tapped
      },300);   //wait 300ms then run single click code
    } else {    //tapped within 300ms of last tap. double tap
      clearTimeout(tapped); //stop single tap callback
      tapped=null
      //insert things you want to do when double tapped
      map.zoomIn(1)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't zoom with double tap on mobile, you need two fingers. You can look at this settings http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-tap and add them to your map.